# DateTime.Parse throwing format exception

Tags: c#, datetime-format, formatexception

I retrieve date and time strings from xml by parsing XElement.
The date and time values are retrieved by
`file.Element("Date").Value` and `file.Element("Time").Value` respectively.

After I retrieve the Date value I parse it to a DateTime variable

```
DateTime dt,ts;
dt = file.Element("Date").Value; // the value is say 12/29/2012
```

and then this dt value is set to a datepicker value on the xaml UI

```
datepicker.Value = dt;
```

I also have a timepicker whose value have to be set by the Time value retrieved from xml.
To set the timepicker value I do the following.
declare 3 strings, say:

```
string a = file.Element("Time").Value; // the value is say 9:55 AM
string b = file.Element("Time").Value.Substring(0, 5) + ":00"; // eg 9:55:00
string c = file.Element("Time").Value.Substring(5); // the value is ' AM'
```

I then concatenate the Date Value and string 'b' and 'c'

```
string total = file.Element("Date").Value + " " + b + c;
```

the value of `total` is now '12/29/2012 9:55:00 AM'

I then try to Parse this `total` string to a DateTime, but it throws a formatexception

```
DateTime.Parse(total, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Did you try to use the CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US") instead of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture?

Comment: I assume the code is actually `DateTime.Parse(total, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` not `DateTime.Parse("total, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture");` as in the post?

Comment: I don't get CreateSpecificCulture option for CultureInfo even though I have used System.Globalization namespace.
However I did try this DateTime.Parse("total", new CultureInfo("en-US"));

It still threw formatexception error

Comment: Yes. The code is DateTime.Parse(total, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for this.
When trying to save the datepicker in XML format, I was saving the value of timepicker as XMLElement as ValueString, hence when converted to string always throwed error.
So I saved it in XML format as Value.ToString().
Now it can convert correctly from String to Date or Time equivalents.

Answer (score 8):

Try [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

```
var dateStr = "12/29/2012 09:55:00 AM";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/kkpC5O).

Read [C# DateTime Format](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format) for format string detail.

**Note** that i have added extra 0 to hour part. It must be 2 digits otherwise format exception will occur.

Comment: I had prepended 0 to my hour part, but it still threw me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: DateTime.ParseExact

```
string total = '12/29/2012 9:55:00 AM'; 
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @Siddharth see my updated answer. Also, refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx for detail.

Comment: Yes I have tried the format given by you, but still it is throwing error.

Comment: When I assign the value of DatePicker value i.e. 
DateTime dt = file.Element("Date").Value to the timepicker, the timepicker takes this value i.e. timepicker.Value = dt
But then timepicker shows wrong value i.e. 12:00:00 AM (default time value if only Date is passed in DateTime.Parse).

Any workaround or help here.